# Flutter Web - Unexpected null value error if code is inserted before return statement in function

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to write a web app where a user selects an image, displays the image as a widget, then has the option to click on a button that says "Upload" to upload it to a server. Being a noob with flutter web, I'm still learning the details and differences between this platform and Android/Windows. As per some reading, unlike an Android/Windows app, the path variable from file_picker is unavailable for web, so I'm in the process of learning how to properly access the image file for uploading.

This is what I've made so far (snippets only):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Selection'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber.shade300,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            whatWidget(result),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: pickImage,
              child: Text('Select Image'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("Upload File/Image"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget whatWidget(FilePickerResult? aFile) {
    return imagePath != null
        ? Image.memory(
            aFile!.files.single.bytes!,
            height: 200,
          )
        : Center(child: const Text('No image selected'));
  }
```

With this code, the app works as expected, but when I insert any code in "whatWidget" before the return statement, I get an "*Unexpected null value*" error.

How should I rewrite the "whatWidget" code so I don't get the error, as my final goal is to actually have one of these three widgets to be returned by the function, based on the file extension passed as the "aFile" parameter: 1) an Image widget if the extension is hpg/png/jpeg; 2) a PDFView widget if the extension is PDF, and 3) a text widget displaying "File format not supported" if the file is either an image nor a PDF file.

Thanks in advance

I tried to modify the whatWidget function by adding some lines of code (variable initialization, so far) before the return statement, expecting them to be executed, but all I get is the "Unexpected null value." error.

Comment: Without seeing the a example code that actually lead to the error you describe it will be very hard to help. *EDIT:* It is also a bit weird that you are checking `imagePath` for null, but then doing a non-null assertion on `aFile`.

Comment: I wanted to see what filename was passed on `aFile` by doing something like `String test = aFile!.files.single.name;`, which I now realize is the source of the null error as on first run, `aFile` really is null. As to the `imagePath` check, it was from an earlier code that I was trying to modify for my purposes . :D

Good thing  the code given by @namra eventually worked. :D

Answer (score 0):

Update your whatWidget with the following code.

```
Widget whatWidget(FilePickerResult? aFile) {
  if (aFile != null && aFile.files.isNotEmpty) {
    final file = aFile.files.single;
    if (file.extension == 'jpg' || file.extension == 'png' || file.extension == 'jpeg') {
      
      return Image.memory(
        file.bytes!,
        height: 200,
      );
    } else if (file.extension == 'pdf') {
      widget)
      return PDFView(
        document: PdfDocument.openData(file.bytes!),
      );
    } else {
      
      return Text('File format not supported');
    }
  } else {
    
    return Center(child: const Text('No image selected'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Namra. This one worked for me. Unfortunately, I still can't upvote yet, so..